# Purpose of associated data with ListView footer in Android?

Tags: android, listview

What is the purpose of the associated data with the Android ListView footer? There is a method to add the footer view to a ListView

```
void addFooterView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)
```

And the documentation on this parameter says:

> Data to associate with this view

However, the documentation did not describe what it actually does. So, what effect does the data parameter have?

Comment: Are you mixing the Footer and Header functions? You asked about `addFooterView`, but wrotte `addHeaderView` in the question. While they are similar, and work closely related, they are 2 different functions

Comment: @Bonatti No, I updated my question to fix the typo. I meant the footer view, but it doesn't really matter, like you said, since I care about the data parameter and both of those functions work similarly.

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, please, mark it as accepted, and leave the question for future reference for new users. If the answer did not help, then edit your question, and explain your doubts further.

Answer (score -2):

The `Object data` returned from Adapter's `getItem` method.

[By documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean))

> Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the list. If this method is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
>
> Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter.

```
Parameters:
v             View: The view to add.
data          Object: Data to associate with this view
isSelectable  boolean: whether the item is selectable
```

Then

[From the Adapters documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29)

> getItem Added in API level 1
>
> Object getItem (int position)
>
> Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.

```
Parameters
position    int: Position of the item whose data we want within the adapter's data set.
Returns
Object      The data at the specified position.
```